# Oracle view permission

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, I attempt to create a view like this

```
create view ddd as
  select * 
    from myschema1.t1 
         join myschema2.t2 
....
```

When I run this statement, I get an error `ORA-01031 : insufficient privileges`.  If I just execute the query in Query Worksheet, however, it works.

Why does my `CREATE VIEW` statement fail and what privileges do I need in order to make the statement succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a view that references `myschema1.t1` and `myschema2.t2`, the user that owns the view has to be given access to those two tables directly, not via a role.  My first guess is that you have been granted the privileges on the underlying table via a role.  You can verify that in SQL*Plus by disabling roles and re-running the query.  If you do

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> select * 
       from myschema1.t1 
            join myschema2.t2 ...
```

does the query work?  If not, then you only have the privileges granted via a role not directly.  Note that if you want to be able to grant other users access to your view, you need to be granted privileges on the objects `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

```
GRANT SELECT ON myschema1.t1 TO <<user that will own the view>> WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ON myschema2.t2 TO <<user that will own the view>> WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If the problem is not with the privileges on the underlying objects, the problem is most likely that you have not been granted the `CREATE VIEW` privilege.

Comment: I tried to grant, but saying ORA-01917: user or role 'myuser' does not exist . I am sure no typo.

Comment: @user595234 - If there are no typos, then the user `myuser` does not exist.  Without seeing exactly what you're typing, I would have to suspect that you're specifying the wrong Oracle user name.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you don't have the `CREATE VIEW` privilege.  If you didn't have access to the tables, you should get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

Comment: Interestingly, and I just had to verify this because your point about the ORA-00942 error makes a whole lot of sense, if you have the `CREATE VIEW` privilege, you have access to a table via a role, but you do not have access to the table directly, creating a view that queries the table returns an ORA-01031 error, not an ORA-00942 error.